# Cup with vinegar/salt/copper solution previously in it ran through dishwasher

Tags: redox, safety, oxidation-state, toxicity

Someone enjoys making jewelry, and saw an online tutorial saying that you can mix equal parts of vinegar and salt, and leave copper in it for a while to oxidize it, and turn it green.

After doing this, dumps the resulting solution down the drain, and runs the plastic cup it was done in through the dishwasher, presumably with some residue left in it, with dishes (ceramic), glasses, and silverware (not real silver, whatever cheap'ish silverware is made with.)

Then afterwards reads other places saying not to do this, because it makes a toxic solution.  Some say it makes copper acetate and copper chloride.  Some say it creates copper ions, which can cause heavy metal poisoning, and to only dispose of it through a hazardous material disposal.  Some say all of this stuff is really toxic, even up to 5ppm.

What would you, someone who understands this stuff, do, and what's the science/chemistry behind your reasoning?

- Nothing, eat on the plates coming right out of the dishwasher.
- Run everything through a few more cycles.
- Replace everything.

I'm thinking running everything through another cycle, and I'd be surprised if there would be a problem after that.

But, I've never learned any chemistry, and wanted to get opinions from people who know things in this area, before blowing it off and eating off things that came in contact with at least a minute amount of this stuff.

Comment: Just run the dishwasher one more cycle and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run everything one more cycle and you are totally safe. Copper is highly soluble in water, so it will entirely dissolve and go away, not contaminating your plates.

Comment: Copper isn't soluble, but _some of_ its compounds are.